# Yii2, find records that match with UNIX timestamps from today

Tags: yii2

I'am trying to find records that match with UNIX timestamps that are from today. Tried some things but cant seem to match it.

```
 $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['a.id' ])
        ->from(['a'=>'shopping_cart'])
        ->andWhere(['>=',new \yii\db\Expression(gmdate("Y-m-d",'updated_at')),new \yii\db\Expression(date('Y-m-d'))])
        ->distinct()
        ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 ->andWhere(['>=',new \yii\db\Expression('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date(now()))')])
```

Comment: You are missing quotes around the expression.